# How do I handle many NULL-able foreign keys in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I hope to make a table of routes that points to a table of flights.

But, the there can be as many as 25 flights per route and I want every flight to be a foreign key.

It seems very wasteful to make a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE routes (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,                                                                              
flight1 INT references "flights" (id),
flight2 INT references "flights" (id),
...
flight24 INT references "flights" (id),
flight25 INT references "flights" (id),
rating INT NOT NULL
);
```

Since, the average number of flights should be around 8. I will just fill the empty flights with NULLs. So the average route will contain 17 NULLs.

Is this the correct way? I looked into arrays of foreign keys of arbitrary length, but those do not seem to be supported on psql (9.3.10)

Comment: You might need an extra table ("junction table") to associate routes with flights.

Comment: Would that junction table still have 25 flight id columns? Or, would the routes table point to the junction table 25 times?

Comment: No, it would become 25 rows (or less) per route.

Comment: Got it. So to ask for all the flights in route 1, just `SELECT flightid FROM rfjunction WHERE routeid = 1` ? Then select all the info from those flight ids?

Comment: Read up on normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way.  You need an additional table.  So, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE routes (
    RouteId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Rating int not null
);

CREATE TABLE RouteFlights (
    RouteFlightId serial primary key,
    RouteId int not null references Routes(RouteId),
    Flight int not null references Flights(FlightId)
);
```

Comment: RouteFlightId might also be not needed, since RouteId and Flight may be used as the primary key in this simple case, but that's also preference.